# Goland not showing on current monitor after detaching HDMI

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, lenovo-laptop

I detached my HDMI Cord and now when I load Goland it starts and then moves off the screen to what should be my HDMDI Screen. I checked my Graphics Options and everything is set for single monitor display. Not sure how to continue. I am using Windows 10 with a Lenovo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change the position of an app window in Windows using keyboard shortcuts, try this:

- 1) Alt+Tab to select the app window (Goland in your case)
- 2) Alt+Space to open the window menu
- 3) Press 'M' to select "Move" from the window menu
- 4) use the arrow keys to move the window back onto your main screen from offscreen